# Two player guessing game in C programming

Tags: c

I have a two player guess random number game; player number (1 0r 2) with turn is randomly generated as the game begins and it's prompted to enter the player number. If the player number entered does not match the random player number then it should print "You have to wait your turn" and return to the enter Player number prompt. My program goes directly to the randome number that is to be guessed by the player instead of going back to asking for player number first and then moving onto asking for entering the random number that's to be guessed by player with his/her turn. How do I get it to go back to asking for the correct player number before moving forward.

Also one correct player number is entered; each player can choose to pass by entering "PASS" twice consecutively and thrice throughout the life of the game. How do I make these conditions work in the game. Thanks in advance to all.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void) { 

    int player_num = 0; int number = 0; int player_input = 0;
    int guess = 0; char input; char str[6] = {0}; int Player_1 = 1;
    int Player_2 = 2; int Pass_1 = 3; int Pass_2 = 3; int i = 1;
    int player_turn = 0; int turn = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));  player_num = 1 + rand() % 2; /* Random number is generated */
    srand(time(NULL));  number = 0 + rand() % 100; /* Random number is generated */

    while(number != guess) {

        printf("\nIt's player's %d turn\n", player_num);
        printf("Player Number?\n");
        scanf("%d", &player_input);

        while (player_num != player_input) {
            printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");
        }

        if (Player_1 != player_num)
            Player_2 = player_num;

        if (i%2 == 1) {
            player_num = Player_1;
        } else {
            player_num = Player_2;
        }

        i = i+1;

        printf("Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100 or Pass: ");

        scanf("%s", str);

        if (strcmp(str, "pass") == 0){
            if (player_num == Player_1){
                Pass_2 = Pass_2 -1;
                printf("Player 2 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", Pass_2);
            }   
            else {
                Pass_1 = Pass_1 -1;
                printf("Player 1 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", Pass_1);
            }
        } else {
            guess = atoi(str);
            if(guess < number) /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");

            else if(guess > number) /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");

            else /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You should call `srand()` just once per run of the program.  By calling it twice, you're undoing any good that you did by calling it once.  You will normally get the same number returned by both calls to `rand()`, which is clearly not what you wanted. Also, you don't need `<malloc.h>` here (and will very seldom need it). The `<stdlib.h>` header is good enough unless you know what extra services `<malloc.h>` provides (which you probably don't since you aren't using any of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **`srand`** needs to be invoked only once and at the start of the program.

Second, **`scanf`** was moved inside the second while loop to force user to enter the correct player number or keep asking until he/she gets it right.

The following code fixes all of the above. Please read the comments in the code to see the reasons for the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(void) { 

 int player_num = 0; int number = 0; int player_input = 0;
 int guess = 0; char input; char str[15] = {0}; // size was increased to compensate for pass pass input
 int Player_1 = 1;
 int Player_2 = 2; int Pass_1 = 3; int Pass_2 = 3; int i = 1;
 int player_turn = 0; int turn = 0; int alternate=0;
 int player1Flag=0,player2Flag=0;

 int lastPlayer=0;

 srand(time(NULL));  
 player_num = 1 + rand() % 2; /* Random number is generated */
 lastPlayer = player_num;
 number = 0 + rand() % 100; /* Random number is generated */

  while(number != guess) {

      while (player_num != player_input)    {
           printf("\nIt's player's %d turn\n", player_num);
           printf("Player Number?\n");
           scanf("%d", &player_input);
           getchar();// to get rid of \n after the input

           if(player_input!=player_num){
               printf("You Have to wait your turn.\n");
           }

      }

      if (Player_1 != player_num) Player_2 = player_num;


      printf("Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100 or Pass: ");

      scanf("%s",str);

     if (strcmp(str, "pass") == 0){
        if (player_num == Player_1){
            player1Flag = player1Flag+1; // flag to detect if last input was a pass

            if(player1Flag>1){
                printf("Dude you passed in your last attempt .. dont be a pus*y\nEnter a guess : ");
                scanf("%s",&str);
                guess = atoi(str);
                if(guess < number){ /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                   printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");
                }else if(guess > number){ /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                   printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");
                }else{ /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                   printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");
                }
                player1Flag = 0; // reset the pass flag = 1 as this pass isn't counted
            }else{
                Pass_2 = Pass_2 -1;
                if(Pass_2<0){
                    printf("You have already passed Thrice\nEnter a guess: ");
                    scanf("%s",&str);
                    guess = atoi(str);
                    if(guess < number){ /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                       printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");
                    }else if(guess > number){ /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                       printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");
                    }else{ /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                       printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");
                    }
                }else{
                    printf("Player 1 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", Pass_2);
                }
            }
        }   
        else{

            player2Flag = player2Flag + 1;

            if(player2Flag>1){
                printf("Dude you passed in your last attempt .. dont be a pus*y\nEnter a guess : ");
                scanf("%s",&str);
                guess = atoi(str);
                if(guess < number){ /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                   printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");
                }else if(guess > number){ /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                   printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");
                }else{ /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                   printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");
                }
                player2Flag=0;// reset the player2Flag = 1 as this pass isn't counted
            }else{
                Pass_1 = Pass_1 -1;
                if(Pass_2<0){
                    printf("You have already passed Thrice\nEnter a guess: ");
                    scanf("%s",&str);
                    guess = atoi(str);
                    if(guess < number){ /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                       printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");
                    }else if(guess > number){ /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                       printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");
                    }else{ /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                       printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");
                    }
                }else{
                    printf("Player 2 has %d more 'Pass' left!\n", Pass_2);
                }
            }
        }   

     }else {

        if (player_num == Player_1){
            player1Flag = 0;//reset pass flag as this player enetered a guess
        }else{
            player2Flag = 0;
        }

        guess = atoi(str);
            if(guess < number){ /* if the guess is lower, output: the guess is too low */
                printf("Your guess was to low.\n ");

            }else if(guess > number){ /* if the guess is higher, output: the guess is too high */
                printf("Your guess was to high.\n ");

            }else{ /* if the guess is equal to the random number: Success!! */
                printf("Yes!! you got it!\n");

             }
      }

      if(lastPlayer==1){
          player_num = 2;
          lastPlayer = 2;
      }else if(lastPlayer==2){
            player_num = 1;
            lastPlayer = 1;
      }

  }   

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sukhvir. Two successive passes means in two attempts. Either player can't enter 'pass' twice in two successive turns or three times for the entire life of the game. For example if player 2 passes the game to Player 1 by entering 'PASS' then when Player 2 gets the turn again he/she must enter a guess and not be allowed to 'PASS'. However either player is allowed three passes for the entire life of the game just not in two successive attempts. sorry for not making this clear before.

Comment: Also,  Right now my prog goes to disply values in minus, "Player2 has -1 more 'PASS' left!" - this is wrong.

Comment: ah ok i get it .. dude i am busy for the next 8 hours .. i will work on it after that and let you know

Comment: I have been working on this with no luck. I am not confident of how to design the logic let alone coding it.

Comment: @TimatyNic .. see the edited code for all the changes you requested ... ask me if you don't understand anything in this code

Comment: 'Pass' logic is working great! but when I play the game in the below sequence, game is not switching player numbers correctly. It's player's 1 turn
Player Number?
2
You Have to wait your turn.

It's player's 1 turn
Player Number?
1
Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100 or Pass: pass
Player 1 has 2 more 'Pass' left!
Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100 or Pass: pass
Player 2 has 2 more 'Pass' left!

It's player's 2 turn
Player Number?

Comment: @TimatyNic Alright buddy .. that problem is now solved as well .. Hope you get good marks for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an input within your while.  In other words, instead of:

```
   while (player_num != player_input)    {
     printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");
   }
```

try this:

```
while (player_num != player_input)    {
   printf("You Have to wait your turn.\nPlayer number?\n");
   scanf("%d", &player_input);
}
```